# Why can I not call borrow_mut() after indexing into an immutable Vec<RefCell>?

Tags: rust

Let's try to compile this code:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Foo {
    v: Vec<RefCell<u8>>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn f(&self, i: usize) {
        let t = &mut *self.v[i].borrow_mut();
        //let t = &mut *{self.v[i].borrow_mut()}; //compiled ok
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Compilation error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow field `self.v` of immutable binding as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:9:23
  |
8 |     fn f(&self, i: usize) {
  |          ----- use `&mut self` here to make mutable
9 |         let t = &mut *self.v[i].borrow_mut();
  |                       ^^^^^^ cannot mutably borrow field of immutable binding
```

Why does this code require adding `&mut self` to function signature in order to compile?

Comment: @Shepmaster Why is compiler tryes to use `IndexMut` instead of `Index`? It's ok?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28935) where `IndexMut` is sometimes selected when `Index` should actually be used.

Your workaround of using `{}` is reasonable, but you can also use `Index` explicitly:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn f(v: Vec<RefCell<u8>>) {
    use std::ops::Index;
    let _t = &mut v.index(0).borrow_mut();
}

fn main() {}
```

See also:

- [Why does a mutable borrow of a closure through DerefMut not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46472082/155423)
- [How to use `BorrowMut` contained within `RefCell`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29074573/155423)

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround is to explicitly call `RefCell::borrow_mut(&v[0])`.