# What is Rust's borrow checker really complaining about here?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider a simple selection sort on a `&mut Vec<&mut String>`:

```
fn selection_sort(collection: &mut Vec<&mut String>) {
    for i in 0..collection.len() {
        let mut least_element = i;
        for j in (i + 1)..collection.len() {
            if collection[j] < collection[least_element] {
                least_element = j;
            }
        }

        collection.swap(least_element, i);
    }
}
```

This loop should work, based on [this](https://medium.com/@spyr1014/sorting-in-rust-selection-insertion-and-counting-sort-2c4d3575e364) and [that](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122790/selection-sort-algorithm-in-rust/122799) – yet the borrow throws this error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a `&` reference as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:58:28
   |
58 |             if chunks[j] < chunks[least_element] {
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
   = help: trait `IndexMut` is required to modify indexed content
```

Or in newer versions of Rust:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in an index of `std::vec::Vec<&mut std::string::String>` as mutable
 --> src/lib.rs:5:32
  |
5 |             if collection[j] < collection[least_element] {
  |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
  |
  = help: trait `IndexMut` is required to modify indexed content, but it is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<&mut std::string::String>`
```

Wouldn't it make more sense to have a `&` reference be mutable?

The [`IndexMut` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) doesn't use an example I understand well and has a pretty large example that doesn't seem to clearly demonstrate how to use `IndexMut`, especially in the context of a selection sort, or swapping elements.

[Error 0596](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0596) explains it occurs when trying to borrow from an immutable value, yet `least_element` is mutable. If `i` is changed to `mut i` this also does compile (and the compiler recommends removing `mut` from `i`).

Is there a Rustacean who can illuminate this?

Comment: I think that the compiler is going crazy trying to decide whether to use `Index` or `IndexMut` while deciding the override of `PartialEq::lt` to use. You can workaround with a couple of temporary variables such as `let a = &collection[j]; let b = &collection[least_element]; if a < b ...`

Comment: Or you can `use std::ops::Index;` and write `if collection.index(j) < collection.index[least_element] ...`

Comment: Or simply `if collection[j].lt(&collection[least_element]) ...`. I'm starting to think that you may have found a compiler bug...

Comment: [`&collection[j] < &collection[least_element]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f554107d08ff7e0ff09b96b37f87a951) also works. Don't know why though.

Comment: So does [`*collection[j] < *collection[least_element]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c66ed3b946e73005b1f1e241ad54d48)

Comment: [Why can I not call borrow_mut() after indexing into an immutable Vec<RefCell>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989901/why-can-i-not-call-borrow-mut-after-indexing-into-an-immutable-vecrefcell) seems to be about the same issue, although it's less clear to me why your example doesn't work. The only thing they obviously have in common is the incorrect choice of `IndexMut` where `Index` would suffice.

Comment: Couldn't find an existing bug, so I filed this [ticket](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64261).

Comment: @edwardw Thanks for filing the issue :) I went to do it but couldn't get the right words for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to access `collection[j]`, the compiler returns a `&mut String` because that's the type of the vector's elements. When you try to access `collection[least_element]`, the borrow checker doesn't know if `least_element != j`, and having two mutable references of the same element would be undefined behavior. You can either use `std::ops::Index` which returns a `&&mut String` (and it's safe to have two immutable references to the same mutable reference), directly borrowing the elements (`&collection[j] < &collection[least_element]`) or, if possible, changing the type of collection to `Vec<&String>` or `Vec<String>`.